# How to show if a complex function with $\arg$ is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

I found an exercise which asks: Determine whether a function is analytic or not without calculating the Cauchy-Riemann conditions.
The functions are

$$
\sin |z|\qquad e^{z^2}\qquad \arg{z^2}\qquad \cos{z^3}
$$

So, the first is not analytic, but why? I tried figure out an answer and I thought that $|z| = \sqrt{z\bar{z}}$, giving the function a dependence on $\bar{z}$ which is clearly a not analytic function. $e^{z^2}$ looks analytic as it only depends on $z$, and likewise $\cos{z^3}$.

But what about $\arg{z^2}$ how to know if it is analytic or not?

Thanks

Comment: A dependence on the conjugate is a good clue. And consequently, dependences on the real part, the imaginary part, the modulus or the argument as well.

Comment: Why the argument as well? Why should the function $\arg$ not be analytic?

Comment: Knowing the argument, there is a direct way to get the modulus and conversely...

Comment: You mean that I can always write $z = |z|e^{i\arg z}$?

Comment: Yep. And you can also get the conjugate.

Comment: A non-constant analytic function can't always be real.

Comment: @RobertIsrael ok this is another valid explanation! $\arg z$ is always a real value, but it's not constant so it cannot be analytic! Great, thanks!